# How to run pipenv python as emacs Python shell

Tags: python, emacs, pipenv

I use python-mode.el and have just discovered [Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/). I can start Python within a project environment from a terminal by first changing to the project directory and entering "pipenv run python". But python-mode wants to execute a process, not a command string.

I tried creating a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/myprojectdir
pipenv run python
```

but got this complaint

```
Warning: the environment variable LANG is not set!
We recommend setting this in ~/.profile (or equivalent) for proper expected behavior.
```

This variable is set in my terminal environment: how do i ensure it's set for pipenv? But the bigger question is, how do i run this pipenv virtual environment python inside emacs to get a buffer with a Python process?

Comment: typically, you use pipenv to create a virtual environment and use `pipenv shell` to enter it.

Comment: I'm trying to enter the virtual environment and run python *in Emacs*, as a python-mode buffer. I can start a shell inside Emacs, and then do `pipenv run python`, but that's still a shell-mode buffer, not a python-mode buffer.

Answer (score 1):

[pipenv.el](https://github.com/pwalsh/pipenv.el) helps here, by setting the appropriate variables and providing a porcelain around Pipenv inside Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i have to explicitly source my .bashrc file (or equivalent). Changing the contents of my `runpipenv.sh` script to this

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
cd ~/myprojectdir
pipenv run python
```

(where my .bashrc file sets `LANG`) and then calling

```
(setq py-shell-name "runpipenv.sh")
```

in Emacs seems to work.